# Trying to get a list of attendees from an events addon

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I have the EventOn plugin, and I'm trying to generate and display a list of user accounts who have purchased a ticket to an event.

The two relevant tables in the DB are the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables. Below is the csv export of the relevant information from them in a google doc:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJCr5Nw6a_ssJMo8xoJOJjHU0r97xzs-olcA-7TQhXw/edit?usp=sharing
I can provide phpMyAdmin access to someone who wants it if it would help to look around.

The first sheet is wp_post table. Second sheet is wp_postmeta. The wp_post ID column is connected to the wp_postmeta table by the post_id column. The wp_postmeta table data there is an example of one purchase. There are more just like it just with a different post_id.

What I need is a SQL statement or a WP_Query statement to get a list of names from the wp_postmeta table for a specific event.

Here's what I've tried so far:

SQL Statement -

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id
where wp_posts.post_type='evo-tix'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='name';
```

WP_Query -

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'evo-tix',
    'meta_key'     => '_eventid',
    'meta_value'   => get_the_ID(),
    'meta_compare' => '=',

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The issue with the SQL statement is that it gives me the names of all purchased for all events. Not sure how to specify an _eventid (from the wp_postmeta table) with it.

The issue with the WP_Query is that it only pulls information from the wp_posts table. It confines it to the correct event (the get_the_ID() method brings in the correct ID/meta_value to be compared to the _eventid meta_key), but I can't get the names from the wp_postmeta table with it.

I'm not sure where to go from here, so any help would be appreciated. If I can help clear something up, let me know. I'm not sure how good of a job I did explaining.

Comment: innerjoins are not so good when there are multiple rows for the same value, the way wp is designed is to return the posts and then return the postmeta needed to render the item. Look at the loop to loop over all posts and get the postmeta. But you might want to cache the result somewhere,

Comment: This was just enough to help me find the missing piece. Thank you!